# MIPS (assembly) - how to round a float number?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, rounding

Let's say I have a float number 123.4567... in $f0 register.

How can I round that to 123,46 and store it to $f1 register?

I need a solution that also works with negative numbers:

-123.4567...  -->  -123.46

edit. And also with integers:

-4.0 --> -4.0

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo code:

```
Multiply by 100.0
If sign is positive
  Add 0.5
Else
  Subtract 0.5
Convert to integer
Convert back to float
Divide by 100.0
```

Comment: ^ That one doesn't work if you try to round for example -4.0:


    -4.0 * 100 = -400.0
    -400.0 + 0.5 = -399.5
    int(-399.5) = -399
    float(-399) = -399.0
    -399,0 / 100.0 = -3.99


So -4,0 gets rounded to -3.99

Comment: @Mike: thanks, yes, my answer was only valid for positive values - I've now updated it so that it works for negative values too.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @PaulR's suggestion, you can either add `+0.5` or `-0.5` if it's positive or negative respectively.

This can either be accomplished with a branch (for clarity):

```
Multiply by 100.0
if num >= 0
    Add 0.5
else
    Add -0.5
Convert to integer
Convert back to float
Divide by 100.0
```

Or if performance is important, by masking the sign bit to get a 0.5 that's positive or negative depending on the sign of your input:

```
Multiply by 100.0
$f2 = $f0 & (0x80000000 | 0.5))
$f0 += $f2
Convert to integer
Convert back to float
Divide by 100.0
```